# onDraw doesn't get called on custom view?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, ondraw

I'm trying to draw a rounded rect with a specific color, but i'm getting nothing. 
I've already done lots of googling, and found some questions like this and read them all. However, none of them solved my problem. Why my `onDraw` method is never called?

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class RoundedTagItem extends RelativeLayout {

    Context ctx;
    String colorString;
    int color;

    public RoundedTagItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;
        color = Color.WHITE;
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        this.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    }

    public RoundedTagItem(Context context, String color) {
        super(context);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.colorString = color;
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        this.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

       if(colorString != null)
             color = Color.parseColor("#" + colorString);

       int rectValue = 35;
       Log.d("Rounded", "rectValue: " + rectValue);
       RectF rect1 = new RectF(0, 0, rectValue, rectValue);

       Paint paint = new Paint();
       paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
       paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       paint.setAntiAlias(true);
       paint.setColor(color);

       canvas.save();
       canvas.drawRoundRect(rect1, 10, 10, paint);
       canvas.restore();

       super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    public void ChangeBackgroundColor(String colorString) {
        color = Color.parseColor(colorString);
        invalidate();
    }

}
```

And then I put icons on this custom view on my main class:

```
// add category items to view
LinearLayout categories = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.detailTagImagesLayout);
for(int i = 0; i < item.getCategoryItems().size(); i++) {

    RoundedTagItem v = null;
    if(i == 0) 
        v = new RoundedTagItem(DetailActivity.this, 
                           item.getCategoryItems().get(i).getColorCode());
    else 
        v = new RoundedTagItem(DetailActivity.this);            

    ImageView img = new ImageView(DetailActivity.this);
    img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(
                     item.getCategoryItems().get(i).getLightIconUrl()));
    v.addView(img);

    v.setTag(i);
    v.setOnClickListener(new TagClickListener());               

    categories.addView(v);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some improvements/problems you can make/fix...

You can move these lines to your constructor:

```
if(colorString != null)
   color = Color.parseColor("#" + colorString);
```

Since this `colorString` never changes and the way you are doing it now you are calculating it every time `onDraw` is called (and he will be called a lot of times).

Second please move your `super.onDraw(canvas)` to your first line.

Third **you need to define your LayoutParams on your constructor.** If a View has 0 width/height its draw will never be called!

```
this.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(150, 150));
```

At last please make sure you are using your `RoundTagItem`. You can add this view to your xml using a tag like this: `<your.package.RoundTagItem>` where `your.package` is the package that you are using (`com.something.blabla`). If you use it like this please be sure you define the `layout_width` and the `layout_height`.

You can also add your view programmatcly by adding to your root view (you get it by using `findViewById(R.layout.your_root)`) or by setting your view as the main content.

```
RoundedTagItem myView = new RoundedTagItem(this);
setContentView(myView);
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i'll do it. But the thing is i'm creating this view dynamically according to size of an array, so i create lots of this view and put them all into a LinearLayout.

Comment: There is no problem with that as long as you have sure that you are display your `LinearLayout`. Make sure you are displaying it (add a text to it before your views) and make the super.onDraw change and tell me if you problem persists.

Comment: I'm using this custom view as a background, and putting on a icon. I see icon, but without background draw. :(

Comment: How do you put an icon on this costum view? You have a `LinearLayout` right? Supose your `LinearLayout` has `android:id=@+id/root`. Now you need to be sure that this `LinearLayout`belongs to the layout you use on your `setContentView`. At last get the layout: `LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.root)` and add your views on this `rootLayout` with `rootLayout.addView(myView)`. If this rootLayout is being drawn, then the views will get a call for their `onDraw` method.

Comment: I've updated my question to show how i add icons on these custom views in my main activity. It seems to me that i've done the same things that you said...

Comment: Do me a favor. Remove your `canvas.save()` and `canvas.restore()`. That log on your `onDraw` is being printed? Did you moved your `super.onDraw()`method to the first line?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17221/discussion-between-tiago-almeida-and-yahya)

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a simple single RelativeLayout XML (rounded_tag_item.xml), and inflate the custom view:

```
public class RoundedTagItem extends RelativeLayout {

    public RoundedTagItem(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context);
    }

    public RoundedTagItem(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context);  
    }

    private void init(Context context) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (inflater != null) {       
            RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.rounded_tag_item, new RelativeLayout(context));

            // rest of stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And how do you plan to set color of that view?

Comment: public RoundedTagItem(Context context, String color) { super(context); init(context,color);}

Comment: or add a setColor(String color) method

Comment: I've already try to create rounded_tag_item.xml but the problem is i need to change background color dynamically, so creating in xml wont solve my problem.

Comment: once you inflate during creation of the custom view, its onDraw method will be called, and you can use the same method you planned to use above